# Perforce Windows plugin not working?

Tags: perforce

Given:
- Installed 64bit Windows perforce plugin
- My workspace root: "c:\source"
- Set "Add workspace root" from plugin preferences
- Right click on file in "c:\source\project1" select check out
- No status icons visible (checked in/out/, out of date, etc,)

Error:
Client '' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create the client by running `p4 client` on the command line or using P4V.

Comment: Where can I run it from from the P4V UI?

Comment: Connection, Edit Current Workspace

Answer (score 13):

Set environmental variable P4CLIENT to your workspace name. Your workspace name is stored in p4 visual client under Connection->Edit Current Workspace

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Using

```
set P4CLIENT=my_workspace_name
```

in the terminal and then using `p4 commnd` has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `~/.p4enviro` config file was using an outdated value for the `P4CLIENT`. I updated the value to the correct name of my current workspace and it fixed the problem.